# I want to have a json response from a controller in mvc (dictionary to json)

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary of FormCollection named values and I want to add a FormNumber that is only a string to it like the response below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Values = FC.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => FC[v]);

string FormNumber="6";
```

[image: this is the response I want]

Comment: Paste your JSON to https://json2csharp.com

Comment: And next time, please post your code as text and not as image.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a model class as a dictionary is limited to the Key and Value properties.

```
public class Model {
    public Model(int num, Dictionary<string, string> values) 
    {
        FormNumber = num;
        Values = values;
    }

    public int FormNumber { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values {get; set;}
}

string FormNumber = "6" 
Dictionary<string, string> Values = FC.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => FC[v]);

// convert to int as your JSON format is int
int number = int.Parse(FormNumber);

Model model = new Model(number, Values);

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var FormNumber = "6";

var ValuesList = Values.Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(c.Key,c.Value) ).ToArray();

var model = new { FormNum = FormNumber, Values =  ValuesList};

return model;

//or I would not recomend

var json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

return json
```